# Querying excel file through ADO Access connection, where are tables stored?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Although I have queried Excel worksheets using an Access ADO connection before, I only thought of the ADO connection as abstract - that is, Access wasn't actually creating a table with my worksheet, and everything "vanished" once I closed the connection.

My thinking changed when I tried explicitly creating a unique table for the first time, and even after closing the connection and exiting the sub, the table still existed somewhere.  Where in my directory is this table stored and aside from dropping the table through another VBA connection is there any other way to view/delete it?

You can see what I mean if you run this sub twice.  The first time it works fine, and the 2nd time a message comes up saying the table already exists.

```vb
Sub stquestion()

Dim acctcon As New ADODB.Connection
Dim acctrec As New ADODB.Recordset

With acctcon
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\name\Documents\Book1.xlsx;" & _
                            "Extended Properties=" & Chr(34) & "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES" & Chr(34) & ";"
    querystr = "CREATE TABLE [tbl1] (cost Numeric(10));"
    .Open
    .Execute querystr
    .Close
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Open Book1.xlsx to see the new worksheet created by your code.

Comment: Haha! Oh wow!  I would NOT have guessed that, thanks!  Along those lines....do you know of how to create a temporary table in this connection, as the `#` syntax I usually use in SQL is giving a syntax error, as is the `CREATE TEMPORARY [tbl1]` suggested on the MSDN page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177893(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Actually it seems like Access doesn't support temp tables at all, contrary to what the MSDN page led me to believe

Comment: Within Access there is no such thing as a temporary table, in the sense you may know about from other databases.  (The documentation is confusing on that point.)  If the provider and target database both support temporary tables, you can do it.  So my guess is it can't be done with Excel.  And if you want the "temporary" table to disappear after you're done with it, you must explicitly delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open an ADO connection to an Excel workbook and then execute a `CREATE TABLE` statement, the "table" you create is a new worksheet.

Open *Book1.xlsx* to see the worksheet created by your code.

When I ran your code with Access 2010 and my workbook, the new sheet was named *_tbl*.  I don't understand why the name was prefixed with an underscore.  If that's an issue, you could rename the sheet afterward.